# How to use Jquery UI AutoComplete on HTML?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some example code of an autocomplete in action but does anyone know how I can make the autocomplete list use an existing list of divs on the page vs the default autocomplete dropdown list that appears when typing into an input?

So given a list of sorts:

```
<div class="school-wrapper">
    <div class="sub-element">
        <div class="school-name">Ariel High</div>
        <div class="status">opened</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-element">
        <div class="school-name">Asta Middle</div>
        <div class="status">opened</div>
    </div>
    ...
```

Based on the snipped of markup above, what I'm wanting to accomplish is this:

- nothing in the input results in the entire school list markup to show (all
  the school names and statuses)
- typing 'Ari' into the input would make the sub-element containing 'Asta Middle' to be hidden and the element containing 'Ariel High' would stay visible
- the default dropdown behavior of autocomplete would be disabled and the hiding of
  elements would actually be done on the child elements of the
  school-wrapper div
- I'm basically trying to figure out how to use
  autocomplete functionality and apply it to the markup of the page
  rather than making the default dropdown show yet another list below
  the input.  I do not know if it can do this but if so, I'm looking
  for direction on how.  I've created the source array for the
  autocomplete thus far.

http://jsfiddle.net/6FUam/2/

Comment: `$("#tags").autocomplete({..` there is no element with id called `tags` can you check it

Comment: whoops, was trying to make things more readable and broke the link in the process.  The link works now.

Comment: Can you be little specific about your problem?

Comment: Not a problem, I've added more specificity to my quandary.

Comment: This is probably the best place to start: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key factor here is to use the autocomplete response.  At least this is one way to do it.  Here's the javascript that makes this work:

```
$("#schools").autocomplete({
    source: schoolSource,
    minLength: 0,
    response: function(event, ui) {
        $.each(ui.content, function(){
            var label = this.label;
            $.each($('.school-name'), function(){
                if($(this).text() === label){
                    $(this).parent().addClass('show');
                }
            });
        });
        $.each($('.school-name'), function(){
            if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('show')){
                $(this).parent().removeClass('visible');
                $(this).parent().addClass('hide');
                $(this).parent().removeClass('show');
            }else{
                $(this).parent().removeClass('hide');
                $(this).parent().addClass('visible');
                $(this).parent().removeClass('show');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

As for my fiddle, the final product and answer is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryurage/ffdmT/